# Two urns, A and B, each with two drawers.

Tags: probability, statistics

If you have two urns, A and B, each with two drawers. The urn A has a gold coin in a drawer and a silver coin in the other drawer while the urn B has a gold coin in each drawer. An urn is chosen at random and then one of its drawers is opened randomly.

a) What is the probability of the coin to be silver?

b) It is checked that the coin is golden. What is the probability of it come from the urn B?

Guys, in the first one I found 25% (could you check if this answer is right? please), The second one I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the first answer correct.   The probability of selecting urn A and then silver from Urn A is indeed: $\tfrac 1 4$.

$$\mathsf P(A\cap S) = \mathsf P(A)\;\mathsf P(S\mid A)$$

---

For the second question:

**Hint**:   Each individual coin had an equal probability of being chosen.   The one chosen was gold.   So how many gold coins were there to choose, and how many of these were in urn $B$?

Or by definition of conditioning:

$$\mathsf P(B\mid G) = \frac{\mathsf P(B\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}$$

Comment: Could you check if 3/4 is right? please.

Comment: @user157308 No, $3/4$ is not right

Answer (score 2):

You need the conditional probability formula
$$p(\text{urn B}|\text{gold is selected})=\frac{p(\text{urn B}\cap\text{gold is selected})}{p(\text{gold is selected})}$$
$$= \frac {\frac 12}{\frac 34}=\frac 23$$

Comment: Could you check if 3/4 is right? please.

Comment: @user157308 $3/4$ is not right.